# Calling git command from PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell

When I call git from a PowerShell script I start to run into problems when I run more complex commands:

```
    # Work fine
    git log

    # Gives error
    git log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^`..HEAD --oneline --count
```

Error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'git': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Is there a good way to encapsulate these long commands when calling them from PowerShell?

Comment: Are you certain that the inner command, `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^`, works by itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$()` to perform the substitution within a string to get this to work.

```
git log "$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^)..HEAD" --oneline --count
```

The backtick character is used as an escape character in PowerShell much like backslash is used in Unix shells.